# Special method in ruby (question mark)

Tags: ruby

How do you define a method of verification? 
The example: include? even? odd?

```
>> 2.odd?
=> false
>> 6.even?
=> true
>>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345843/ruby-question-mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Integer
  def is_even?  
    self.remainder(2) == 0
    # this is either true or false, just what we want
  end
end

p 4.is_even?
#=> true
```

Answer (score 10):

The same way you define any other function - the question mark is part of the function name:

```
def is_it?
    return (...)
end
```

Cheers!