# Ruby Struct instance cannot find attributes which have '?' in their name

Tags: ruby

If I create a Struct with an attribute which contains a question mark, any instance of that class will not be able to find that method. For e.g.

```
    Test = Struct.new(:value, :value?)
    t = Test.new(true,true)
    t.value
      => true
    t.value?
    NoMethodError: undefined method `value?' for #<struct Test value=true, :value?=true>
```

Any idea ? I am using Ruby 1.9.3-p286.

Comment: The implementation of `Struct` is quite complicated and I do not have the time to determine the exact mechanism of the issue you've encountered... however, question marks are not allowed in Ruby variable names. It seems likely that somewhere between initializing your `Struct` and accessing the `value?` member, this lexical restriction is biting you, perhaps because `Struct` attempts to store its members as instance variables?

Comment: @Mohan: mdunsmuir is only partially correct. In Ruby, almost everything is allowed, even methods with names such as `42`, try `o = Object.new; o.define_singleton_method "42" do true end; o.send "42"` :-)

Comment: @mdunsmuir: No, not right. Ruby allows ? in method names, and instance variable accessors are just methods. However, you cannot have something like `@thing?`.

Comment: @Linuxios Did I say that you cannot have method names containing question marks? I do not believe I did.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Method names with question marks are allowed. Variable names with question marks are not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448938/in-ruby-a-variable-name-cannot-end-with-such-as-has-completed-but-a-meth

Comment: @mdunsmuir: Sorry. I ment to just say that they were allowed in method names. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo'll have to concede that some method names in Ruby are special. For example, if you defined method

```
o = Object.new
def o.kokot= n
  return n + 1
end
```

And call

```
o.kokot 1
#=> 1
```

The result will still be 1, not 2 as you might expect. This is peculiarity of `=` sign in method names. In your case of Structs, question mark seems to have such peculiarity, too, which prevents you from retrieving value by calling:

```
t.value?
```

You have to call

```
t[:value?]
```

That's it, have a nice day.

Comment: A question mark at the end of a method name has *no* special meaning in Ruby. It is simply allowed.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. That would mean that the problem is solely in the `Struct` implementation, right?

Comment: Indeed. This appears to be an issue with Struct’s internals, or just the fact that `?` is not valid in a variable name.

Comment: My gut is telling me that the second thing you mentioned, that will be it.