# Why can't punctuation (? and !) be used in Ruby variable names?

Tags: ruby

? and ! are used in method names, but apparently cannot be used in variable names?

```
foo! = 2
=> SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '='
```

What is the reason?

Comment: Because Ruby's syntax says so. The reason of that (in case it's not clear) isn't a question for SO :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448938/in-ruby-a-variable-name-cannot-end-with-such-as-has-completed-but-a-meth?rq=1

Comment: @sawa - Thanks for the helpful and interesting link. I wonder why when I search SO for something I don't find it, and others apparently do.

Answer (score 3):

? and ! are ruby operators, so they are not allowed in variable names.  Otherwise, how will Ruby evaluate something like `if (v!=2)` (expression that checks whether a variable v is not equal to 2) or something like  `v?1:0` (expression that will return 1 if v is truthy and 0 if its falsy)

UPDATE
Another plausible reason is that Ruby treats names ending with ? and ! as methods

Comment: So why is it legal to call a method `v!`? Would that not cause the same problem?

Comment: I guess the interpreter does not face the same dilemma when dealing with function names, hence, function names can contain ? and !.  I believe it has something to do with function calling syntax and function is typicallly on RHS of expression

Comment: it's exactly the same dilemma with functions, so this answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Give an example where such dilemma can occur with functions.  If you extend the question to mean "Why a variable cannot end with =, +, -, *, etc.", my answer still holds good.

Comment: `arr.empty ? fn : a` is something different than `arr.empty? fn :a` . The former will call `arr.empty` and switch on its results. The latter will call `fn` with the argument `:a` and then send the results to `arr.empty?`.

Comment: Only other reason I can see for ? and ! not allowed in variable names is because these are allowed to be last character in function names to offer syntactic sugar.