# test(?e, ARGV[0])

Tags: ruby

What is the test function in the next Ruby expression:

```
unless ARGV.size == 1 and test(?e, ARGV[0])
```

Comment: Read the doc: `ri Kernel#test` or http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001389

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test()` seems to be reminiscent of the shell tests to see if files or directories exist, are readable, etc:

```
irb(main):011:0> test(?e,"/etc/passwd")  # e for exist
=> true
irb(main):012:0> test(?e,"/does/not/exist")
=> false
irb(main):014:0> test(?e,"/etc")
=> true
irb(main):015:0> test(?d, "/etc")        # d for directory
=> true
irb(main):016:0> test(?d, "/etc/passwd")
=> false
irb(main):017:0> test(?r, "/etc/passwd") # r for readable
=> true
irb(main):018:0> test(?w, "/etc/passwd") # w for writable
=> false
```

Full details are in the `ri Kernel#test` documentation.