# Ternary operator syntax error

Tags: ruby

New to ruby, exploring the teranary operator.

This works just as expected:

```
5==5? "x" : "y"
```

returns "x", as everything in ruby is an expression.

But, this doesn't...

```
user.birthday? "x" : "y"
```

It's suppose to check if birthday is nil, and return the appropriate string. But it gives me a syntax error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
user.birthday? "x" : "y"
                    ^
```

What's so different about this statement comapred to the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Methods can and often do end with a [question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179016/what-is-the-purpose-of-and-at-the-end-of-method-names) in ruby.

```
user.birthday ? "x" : "y"
```

Comment: Thanks. But 5==5? returns a boolean, and user.birthday? does too. So why doesn't it work like that? In both cases, the syntax comes down to: BOOL IFSTATEMENT : ELSESTATEMENT (PS - I will accept your answer in 7 minutes)

Comment: In `user.birthday?` the question mark is part of the method name, so there is not a ternary (?) operator.

Comment: @0xSina: Add the implied parentheses to `user.birthday? "x" : "y"` and you get `user.birthday?("x" : "y")` (which doesn't make any sense at all).

Comment: @muistooshort makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case user.birthday? ? 'x' : 'y' will do the trick if you want to check if birthday is not nil/false.

Answer (score -2):

ruby is a Object Oriented Programming language so all method definitions are inheritance from a class, and that comes like a "true",try this:

`class User`

```
def birthday(confirm)
    return true
end
```

end

us = User.new()

us.birthday("My birthday")

rep= us.birthday("My birthday") ? "x": "y"

puts rep

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are saying here, but I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the issue. The problem is that `birthday?` is acting like a method instead of a ternary operation.

Comment: The error comes out because the variable and the method does not exist so you need to declarate them.