# How does `?n` differ from `'n'`?

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-1.8

Chris Pine's *How to Program* mentions that the following:

```
?T
```

should return `84`. When I run it, it returns `"T"`. My suspicion is that there is a version difference. My guess is that `?` is an `Array` or `String` method, but I cannot find documentation. What does `?T` do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this context, `?` with a character is a literal single character string. Therefore `?T` is the String "T" and `puts ?T` is the same as `puts "T"` You can throw it into IRB to check it out:

```
1.9.3p429 :002 > ?T
 => "T" 
1.9.3p429 :001 > ?T.class
 => String 
1.9.3p429 :003 > puts ?T
T
 => nil
```

Related Existing SO Questions and Answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1878406/504685
- [What does the unary question mark (?) operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16641205/504685)

Edit to add: Per a comment on the answer linked above this might have been a change in ruby 1.9 to return a single character String instead of the ASCII character value. (which the ASCII value of T is 84 )

```
1.9.3p429 :006 > ?T.ord
 => 84
```

Comment: It was a change in Ruby 1.9+.