# How to send params to controller

Tags: grails, parameters

I am new with groovy/grails. Want to ask what is the difference between:

```
String x = params?.var1
```

and

```
String x=params.var1
```

Why do we use that "?"  in controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the question mark operator mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345843/what-does-the-question-mark-operator-mean-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` is called **Safe Navifation** operator in Groovy. It means that it will silently catch NullPointerException if it happens and return null instead. For example:

```
Map params = null
String x = params?.var1 // assigns null to variable x
String y = params.var1 // throws NullPointerException because params is null
```

It's pretty useful if you assume that specific variable may be a `null` and you don't want to check if it's not null every time. In this case you use safe navigation operator instead and you accept that the result of chained calls may return `null`.

> Reference: http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator

Comment: Thankssss so much @Szymon

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)