# Don't understand a bit of code RUBY = [*?a..?z]

Tags: ruby

I found this code from a few years back.
I understand what this code does but not how.
Could anyone explain what the `*` and the `?` are doing here? I haven't seen them used like this before.

```
myarr = [*?a..?z]       #generates an array of strings for each letter a to z
myarr = [*?a..?z] + [*?0..?9] # array of strings a-z and 0-9
```

Comment: [Star](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918475/6611487) & [Question Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1345854/6611487) in Ruby

Comment: FYI: `[*?a..?z] + [*?0..?9]` can be combined into a single `[*?a..?z, *?0..?9]`

Comment: Yes thanks Im not actually using this code I was just curious as to what was going on behind the scenes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?` is just a character literal syntax, it used to have special meaning in ruby < 1.9, but now `?a` is just the same as doing `"a"`

Then `..` is creating a [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html) and `*` just expands that into an argument list and the `[` `]` pair turn that into an array.

Wish my google-fu was enough to get some decent documentation links or explanations beyond that, but searching for these ones is extremely difficult.

Updated: `?a` is actually the same as `"a"` not `'a'` as mentioned earlier. To see this run (IRB tags left in to help illustrate what's happening):

```
irb(main):001:0> print ?\t
    => nil
irb(main):002:0> print "\t"
    => nil
irb(main):003:0> print '\t'
\t=> nil
irb(main):004:0>
```

Comment: More specifically, `*` expands the range into an argument list and `[...]` turns these arguments into an array.

Comment: For completeness, I'll mention that these days it is typically done `*('a'..'z')` or `('a'..'z').to_a`.

Comment: @Mark,perhaps obvious, but I'll note that `*('a'..'z')` can only be used as an argument; for an assignment, `a = [*('a'..'z')]` or `a = ('a'..'z').to_a`.